# New Year 2015 resolutions for this community?

Tags: discussion

first and foremost ,Happy New Year 2015 to all .So what are your new resolutions for this site .Mine will be to spend at-least half an hour daily for this community ,helping folks .Any innovative ideas or resolutions for this up coming year?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My resolutions for 2015 are to

A) Be a better person & a better developer :) than I was last year

B) Help others more

C) Learn from others more

D) Evangelise Salesforce1, Mobile SDK and Lightning more than ever because I strongly feed that although these are some of the most commonly used frameworks, they aren't promoted/ backed enough.

Answer (score 5):

Mine is to help more people learn to code!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to have to say, try to learn more from other people.  I keep finding out interesting tidbits from other posters answers/questions, but I never manage to look more into what I learn.  One example was Frameworks.  I really want to spend some time researching some.  The TriggerX framework looked really nice...